# How can I modify MachineKey for s Session State Server?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state

I'm trying to implement a SessionState server to allow multiple web servers to share the same state. At first this will be the different development machines, and later it'll be the different web servers in the web farm.

So far, I'm making good progress I think, but one of the requirements has me confused. In order to implement this, I need to make sure that all web servers are using the same machine key.

This is a sample MachineKey taken from my local development machine:

```
<section name="machineKey"
    type="System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
```

If we have a Session State Server deployed locally, do we need to ensure that all other machines using this service (specifically, the other developers working on the same project, and then when we deploy to the web farm) have the exact same entry in their Machine.Config files?

Or do I have to somehow generate a new machine key that can apply to all the machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this:

*[ASP.NET machineKey Generator](http://www.developmentnow.com/articles/machinekey_generator.aspx)*

Comment: harsh - -1 because a link I posted in July is returning a 404 now. It worked when I posted it buddy

Comment: Since I'm really feeling sorry you, I asked this question on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71259/does-an-old-answer-that-contains-only-a-dead-link-deserve-a-downvote

Comment: Ok fair enough GvS. +1 on your meta question, 'cause you're conscientious. & Thanks to Software Monkey too

Answer (score 0):

The MachineKey is the key, and the session gets encrypted to the user.

That means, they are only useful on the web servers, as they are encrypting it to the client requests.

I think the SessionState machine key is not important at all (but I didn’t find now the documentation stating that...)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If 3 devs are all using the same machine key - basically the same string I've specified above, shouldn't they all be able to use the same session state server, when running their applicatons on their local IIS?

Comment: a machine key entry looks like this
'<system.web>
<machineKey validationKey="<ValidationKey>" decryptionKey="<decryptionKey>" decryption="3DES" validation="SHA1" />
</system.web>' 
that should be placed in your web.config. and its only used for talking through the client's machine. All your dev and server machines should have the same (at least in the same environment,.. test, live, etc)